# How to make sure not to move SCN Nodes with respect to camera

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have created view entities like Point , Line, Text into the SCN scene.
But once created, if I move my camera, even these entities are moving with respect to the camera.

I want to keep these entities (say, SCN Nodes) in the same position( the coordinates,which I used while creating them).

for example,I am using the below function to create a point.

```
// add dot node with given position
func nodeWithPosition(_ position: SCNVector3) -> SCNNode {
    // create sphere geometry with radius
    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 0.01)
    // set color
    sphere.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(red: 255/255.0,
                                                     green: 153/255.0,
                                                     blue: 83/255.0,
                                                     alpha: 1)
    // set lighting model
    sphere.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .constant
    sphere.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
    // create node with 'sphere' geometry
    let node = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
    node.position = position

    return node
}
```

The above function can be used like this:

```
let node = self.nodeWithPosition(position)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
```

I would be really glad if someone can help me.

Comment: It might be the size of your nodes. Would you post the codes.

Comment: @AlokSubedi: just edited my post.

Comment: Not the problem I thought of. Totally looks normal. Try `showWorldOrigin` on `debugOption` to see if it is just node moving or whole ar world.

Comment: what do you mean by whole ARWorld moving??